# Permutations of matrix elements such that each element is in the same row OR in the same column

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

Suppose you have a rectangular table of size $n\times m$. I want to permute its cells in such a way that image of any cell $C$ lies in the same row **or** in the same column as $C$.

For example, if you have a 2x2 table $\begin{bmatrix}
a & b \\
c & d 
\end{bmatrix}$, then one of possible permutations is $\begin{bmatrix}
b & d \\
a & c 
\end{bmatrix}$

The queston is, **how to count the number of all such permutations of $n\times m$ table** ? I don't expect that there would be a nice closed-form answer, so, any formula will do.

I can only get the answer for $2\times m$ table.

Suppose you have a table $\begin{bmatrix}
a_1 & a_2 &a_3 &... &a_m \\
b_1 & b_2 &b_3 &... &b_m 
\end{bmatrix}$

In order to describe a permutation, select which $a_i$'s will jump "downstairs" and which $b_i$'s will jump "upstairs". If $k$ of $a_i$'s move down, then $k$ of $b_i$'s should move up. After that, $m-k$ of the remaining $a_j$'s in the upper row can be placed in $(m-k)!$ ways, and $b_j$'s in the bottom row can be placed in $(m-k)!$ ways as well, so the answer for $2\times m$ table is $$\sum_{k=0}^{m} \binom{m}{k}^2 ((m-k)!)^2$$
which is [A006040](http://oeis.org/A006040) in OEIS.

I also wrote [a program](https://github.com/liaombro/math/blob/main/sameroworcolumn.py) to calculate the answer for 3x3 table, which is 2720. The answer for $2\times 2$ table is 9, but unfortunately, there is no sequence in OEIS containing "9, 2720".

Comment: http://oeis.org/search?q=6+82+2720&sort=&language=&go=Search http://oeis.org/search?q=24+1313+194568&sort=&language=&go=Search and http://oeis.org/A188808 which has the full array

Comment: [Here](https://tio.run/##jVLLboMwEDzjr1ilSmXHoQ059GLIj0Q9EGNSJGwexr1U@Xa6No8iVarKYbWe8c7OepFtG9@lHMenysjaFQrSWzXYVzsUkvOXjwtxtjJ3MLlWts2lAmQEmdG6hgzqxmcYxIy6ADtjq7tRxZYnyJS0MgOYo4@afZEo8pntXN4ri3XmoAWCeNM6jeeTP5VNTwNyy04CI6RAEwTSdK1kHuc8KEbRp5JD00OK2hfoqWHiNyypnmEvH1x49XRWFHZVQ48lxY6hHzB49k5gJaOov9pX/c65WBF5tfst8iA/EY1Psyb/bo9shwVTH@AwyYu/3EEXx8sF3@6QQSc2LkJR27SycWbAFNfGfCVD@fVR92dgYRFx5j1P9aq2KoB8Bb1krwbXG08I8iAkLDivDA1TLDPqLBE6fRN6nQ77D956Sc9HzXy2g92iuZDKFDX@Pw8yjslp830D)  is a code to calculate them.

Comment: You need c++20, it runs in $2^{nm}$ time and uses inclusion exclusion, but you would have to replace the long long with a biginteger class because the main limitation is it overflows.